# Pelican pose control accuracy

Tags: ros, quadcopter, uav

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

This question mainly to all those ROS UAV users working with an Asctec Pelican quadrotor: what's the typical hovering accuracy you can obtain? I got a first basic controller working but, before I start trying to optimize is, would like to have an idea of the typical performance I can achieve.

regards,

Steven

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9143/pelican-pose-control-accuracy/) by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2011-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since your question isn't about ROS, it should be asked elsewhere, such as on the [asctec-users mailing list](http://asctec-users.986163.n3.nabble.com/).

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2011-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1